# Real-time results based on NSSearchField

Tags: swift, cocoa, nssearchfield

Been searching around here and elsewhere, but couldn't find anyone who had solved and posted about it.

Trying to mimic something like the view that opens if you start typing in the Safari address bar, the Spotlight textfield or e.g. the mail app that ships with macOS.

I found people talking about Apple using private methods, just curious if anyone came up with a custom solution other than the one posted by Apple themselves.

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: How did Apple do it? Can you post a link?

Comment: See here, it is Objective-C, but the concept works in Swift as well: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/CustomMenus/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Safari and Spotlight do something similar. If you want something less complicated, use text completion and `optional func control(_ control: NSControl, textView: NSTextView, completions words: [String], forPartialWordRange charRange: NSRange, indexOfSelectedItem index: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>) -> [String]` of `NSControlTextEditingDelegate`.